# How long would it take to dissolve someone using fluoroantimonic acid?

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, chemical-biology

After writing [an answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21908/how-can-i-liquefy-my-enemies/21911#21911) on worldbuilding.SE, I came here to ask a question. How long would it take to dissolve a human body using fluoroantimonic acid?

I understand that since the human body isn't homogenous, it's a bit tough to get the exact calculation, but lets say we create a mannequin using the material in the human body that fluoroantimonic acid takes the longest time to dissolve - how long would it take?

Comment: As for the question, my gut answer is no. Acids are not magic dissolving fluids. You'll certainly hydrolyze the living daylights out of esters and related bonds, of course.

Comment: @etherealflux we already know it takes 2 days (roughly) to dissolve a body in a vat of sulfuric acid. That tells me that it's at least possible to do the task at hand with an acid that basically dissolves anything not teflon.

Comment: @etherealflux Funnily enough, an acid weaker than fluoroantimonic acid was named ["magic acid"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_acid), because of its surprising ability to protonate even alkanes, meaning it could dissolve a candle.

Comment: Welp, that'll do the trick. I remember reading about that once - stabilizing carbocations is **insane**.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/is-there-any-chemical-mixture-which-could-liquidize-a-person-in-a-couple-minutes

Comment: Unfortunately for the asker of the worldbuilding.se question, the result will not be all liquid -- there will be a *lot* of off-gassing gaseous.  This acid will dissolve organic compounds to produce lots of hydrogen, methane, steam, and/or HF.

Comment: @CurtF. and that is just fine, the only requirement for that other question was that the resulting mess be liquidy - it makes no mention of the amount of liquid required. The bigger question we're trying to get answered is how long it will take for the entire thing to happen.

Comment: Closed in accordance with the [meta discussion](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2874/4945).